# If $1 \leq x_i \leq n$ and $k < n $ what is the value of $\sum_{x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_k \; | \; \sum^k_{i = 1} x_i = n} \sum_{i < j} x_i x_j $

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, graph-theory, coloring

Given positive integers $n$ and $k$ such that $1<k<n$, let $S(n,k)$ be the set of postiive integer $k$-tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ for which $\displaystyle\sum^k_{i = 1} x_i = n$. For example, $S(5,3)=\{(3,1,1),(1,3,1),(1,1,3),(2,2,1),(2,1,2),(1,2,2)\}$.

**Question 1:** What is the value of
$$\displaystyle \phi(n,k) = \sum_{\displaystyle (x_1,\cdots, x_k)\in S(n,k)}\; \displaystyle \sum_{i < j} x_i x_j \qquad ?$$
If this value cannot be determined exactly by simpler formula, can we at least give some simple bounds?

Note $$\displaystyle \phi(n,k) = \displaystyle \sum_{\displaystyle (x_1,\dots,x_k)\in S(n,k)}\displaystyle  (n^2 - (\displaystyle \sum_{i} x^2_i))/2 \leq \displaystyle \binom{n-1}{k-1} \displaystyle n^2 (1 - 1/k) /2 $$  and
$$\displaystyle \phi(n,k) \geq \binom{n-1}{k-1} k(2n-k)/2$$

**Question 2:**

Let
$$\displaystyle f(k,p) = \binom{n-1}{k-1} \times \displaystyle p^{\displaystyle  \displaystyle \sum_{i < j} x_i x_j} \leq \binom{n-1}{k-1} \times \displaystyle p^{\displaystyle  \displaystyle n^2 (1 - 1/k) /2}  $$ It is known $\displaystyle \sum^n_{k=1} f(k,p) = 1$. Can we get a tight bound?

**Origin** The first question calculates the total possible greedy coloring can generate color $k$ in a graph of $n$ vertices. The second question calculates the probability that greedy coloring will generate color $k$ in the Erdos-Reyni graph $G(n,p)$.

Comment: The answer will obviously depend on the exact values of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$. Is the problem about finding the _bounds_ (i.e. the maximum and the minimum) of that sum, given the restrictions? Or do you want something else?

Comment: @StinkingBishop bounds will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(n,k)$ be the desired sum. We can work out recursive formulas for it. If $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i=n$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_i=n-x_k$. So, writing $m$ in place of $x_k$ we get

\begin{align*}
g(n,k)&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k+1} \left(g(n-m,k-1)+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_im\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k+1} \left(g(n-m,k-1)+(n-m)m\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k+1} g(n-m,k-1)+\frac{n(n-k+1)(n-k+2)}{2}-\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k+2)(2n-2k+3)}{6}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-k+1} g(n-m,k-1)+\frac{(n+2k-3)(n-k+1)(n-k+2)}{6}
\end{align*}
The starting value is if $k=1$ then $g(n,1)=0$. Then for $k=2$ we get

$$g(n,2)=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)n}{6}$$
and
\begin{align*}
g(n,3)&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-2} g(n-m,2)+\frac{(n+1)(n-1)n}{6}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-2} \frac{(n-m+1)(n-m-1)(n-m)}{6}+\frac{(n+1)(n-1)n}{6}
\end{align*}
which, using Faulhaber's formulas, you can work out is a degree 4 polynomial in $n$, and in general, $g(n,k)$ is a degree $k+1$ polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Ok, complex but correct. Please use something other than $f$ to represent the sum as f(k) is used to represent the 2nd problem in post.